# jquery accordion but load content from another script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So i have a website with links, I have seen this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ BUT I want when someone clicks on a link in the accordion to open up and load content from a php script i have and not be preloaded like this

```
<h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis       porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
```

on page load but upon click to open up and LOAD the dynamic content from my external php script (which is being passed a value to return results on each link click) how do we do this ? i have searched everywhere and all examples are for static content preloaded in the html, I need load the link upon click

cheers

Comment: would have to give each section an Id etc and use the accordion events (activate), then get the id and using ajax load the content...

Answer (score 0):

A way to load dynamically the content in each panel with [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is:

- use the [beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate) event
- disable accordion  before loading and enable again accordion when load finishes.
- you can use the "ui.newHeader" argument to test which will be the new panel
- you can use ui.newPanel as the div element for wich you want to load content

Avoid to load a full HTML page in an accordion panel. If you are interested to load a full html page you need to insert the content as an iframe inside the div.

```js
$(function () {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
      // in order to avoid to re-load the same data use a data attribute
      if (ui.newPanel.data('already-loaded') !== undefined) {
        return;
      }
      ui.newPanel.data('already-loaded', true);
      // disable accordion to wait for loading finishes
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", true );
      switch (ui.newHeader.text()) {
        case 'Section 1':
          ui.newPanel.load('page1.html', function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
            this.append('Section 1 loaded');
          });
          break;
        case 'Section 2':
          ui.newPanel.load('page2.html', function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
            this.append('Section 2 loaded');
          });
          break;
        case 'Section 3':
          ui.newPanel.load('page3.html', function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
            this.append('Section 3 loaded');
          });
          break;
        case 'Section 4':
          ui.newPanel.load('page4.html', function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
            this.append('Section 4 loaded');
          });
          break;
        default:
          $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So using the Accordion's events you could do the following:

JS:

```
  $("#accordion").on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function(event,ui) {
     var panel = ui.newHeader[0];
     var requiredURL = $(panel).data('url');

      $.ajax({
        url : requiredURL,
        success : function(res){
          ui.newPanel[0].innerHTML = res;
        },
        error : function(msg){

        }
      });

  });
```

Then on each H3 of the accordion header add the url or the data you need like:

```
<h3 data-url="the-url-to-load-content">
```

Hard for me to test but something like above might be what your afterish.